# ビット演算子だけで整数の割り算（余あり）をする方法

Tags: アルゴリズム

掛け算の場合は

```
5 * 10 = 0b101 * 0b1010
       = 0b101 * (2^3 + 2^1)
       = (0b101 << 3) + (0b101 << 1) = 0b110010 = 50
```

で計算できるのは分かるのですが、5/3などを計算する場合どうすればいいのか思い当たらないので説明いただければと思います。
そのまま割る方法でも、1/3をバイナリで表現する方法でも大丈夫です（5 * 1/3 と出来るので）。

Comment: 例示されているのは**整数**の乗算ですよね。小数の乗算の方法は理解されているのでしょうか。

Comment: 浮動小数点での計算という意味ではなく、小数点になりうる割り算って意味だったんですけど、タイトル分かりにくかったぽいので直します。すいません。

Comment: `+`はビット演算子ではないけど、`+`, `-`, あるいは比較演算子は使用可？

Comment: `+`、`-`はビットだけでの実装が簡単なんで使っていただいて大丈夫です。比較演算子も大丈夫ですが、出来れば割り算に使ってる数字本体に対してはさけていただければ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

下記コードは、割り算の筆算アルゴリズムを2進数でそのまま実装したものです。（C言語を使用）

```c
void div(int n, int d)
{
  int m = 1, q = 0;
  while (d <= n) {
    d <<= 1;
    m <<= 1;
  }
  while (1 < m) {
    d >>= 1;
    m >>= 1;
    if (n >= d) {
      n -= d;
      q |= m;
    }
  }
  // q=商 / n=余り
}
```

LiveDemo: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/blNO0ai7MChwg4a0

Answer (score 2):

実用性がまるでありませんが、ビット演算子**のみ**を利用した除算の例です。
`+`, `-`, 比較演算子, ループは使用していません。

http://ideone.com/FMuNWh

```
#include <stdio.h>

char add(char a, char b)
{
    char r = 0;
    char n = 0;
    r |= (a & 0x1) ^ (b & 0x1);
    n =  (a & 0x1) & (b & 0x1);
    r |= (((a >> 1) & 0x1) ^ ((b >> 1) & 0x1) ^ n) << 1;
    n = (((a >> 1) & 0x1) & ((b >> 1) & 0x1)) | (((a >> 1) & 0x1) & n) | (n & ((b >> 1) & 0x1));
    r |= (((a >> 2) & 0x1) ^ ((b >> 2) & 0x1) ^ n) << 2;
    n = (((a >> 2) & 0x1) & ((b >> 2) & 0x1)) | (((a >> 2) & 0x1) & n) | (n & ((b >> 2) & 0x1));
    r |= (((a >> 3) & 0x1) ^ ((b >> 3) & 0x1) ^ n) << 3;
    n = (((a >> 3) & 0x1) & ((b >> 3) & 0x1)) | (((a >> 3) & 0x1) & n) | (n & ((b >> 3) & 0x1));
    r |= (((a >> 4) & 0x1) ^ ((b >> 4) & 0x1) ^ n) << 4;
    n = (((a >> 4) & 0x1) & ((b >> 4) & 0x1)) | (((a >> 4) & 0x1) & n) | (n & ((b >> 4) & 0x1));
    r |= (((a >> 5) & 0x1) ^ ((b >> 5) & 0x1) ^ n) << 5;
    n = (((a >> 5) & 0x1) & ((b >> 5) & 0x1)) | (((a >> 5) & 0x1) & n) | (n & ((b >> 5) & 0x1));
    r |= (((a >> 6) & 0x1) ^ ((b >> 6) & 0x1) ^ n) << 6;
    n = (((a >> 6) & 0x1) & ((b >> 6) & 0x1)) | (((a >> 6) & 0x1) & n) | (n & ((b >> 6) & 0x1));
    r |= (((a >> 7) & 0x1) ^ ((b >> 7) & 0x1) ^ n) << 7;
    return r;
}

char sub(char a, char b)
{
    return add(a, add(~b, 1));
}

char cmp(char a, char b, char c)
{
    return (~(add(~add(a, b), add(c, 1)) >> 7)) & 0x1;
}

char mask(char a)
{
    return (a | a << 1 | a << 2 | a << 3 | a << 4 | a << 5 | a << 6 | a << 7);
}

char ds(char *sum, char *d, char *r, char a, char b)
{
    char c = cmp(*sum, b, a); *d = add(*d, c); *sum = add(*sum, b & mask(c)); *r = sub(*r, b & mask(c));
}

char ds8(char *sum, char *d, char *r, char a, char b)
{
    ds(sum, d, r, a, b); ds(sum, d, r, a, b); ds(sum, d, r, a, b); ds(sum, d, r, a, b);
    ds(sum, d, r, a, b); ds(sum, d, r, a, b); ds(sum, d, r, a, b); ds(sum, d, r, a, b);
}

char ds128(char *sum, char *d, char *r, char a, char b)
{
    ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b);
    ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b);
    ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b);
    ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b); ds8(sum, d, r, a, b);
}

char div(char a, char b, char *r)
{
    char sum = 0, d = 0;
    *r = a;
    ds128(&sum, &d, r, a, b); 
    return d;
}

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    char reminder, division;
    scanf("%d / %d", &a, &b);
    division = div(a, b, &reminder);
    printf("%d / %d = %d (%d)", a, b, division, reminder);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 出来ればdsなどの関数が何をしているのか軽く説明つけれますか？